# Divisibility of a power sum by a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For a given prime $p>2$ and positive integer $k$, let $$S_k=1^k+2^k+...+(p-1)^k$$ We have to find the values of $k$ for which $p|S_k$. By the binomial theorem we know that $p|i^k+(p-i)^k$ when $k$ is odd. Since $p>2$, $p$ must be odd. Hence for every odd $k$, $p|S_k$. When $k=p-1$, $i^k \equiv 1(\mod p)$ by Fermat's little theorem. $$\therefore S_{p-1}\equiv 1+1+...+1\equiv p-1\equiv -1(\mod p)$$ $\therefore$ $p\not|S_{p-1}$. When $k=2$, $$S_2=1^2+2^2+...+(p-1)^2=\frac {(p-1)p(2p-1)}6\equiv 0(\mod p)$$Therefore $p|S_2$ except when $p=3$ as proved earlier. Even when $k=4$ and $k=p+1$, we find that $p|S_4\space\text{(for $p\not=5$) and}\space S_{p+1}$. Does it hold for all even $k$ except when $k=p-1$? If so how do I prove it?

Comment: $1+16+81+256=354\not\equiv 0 \mod 5$ ... when $k=p-1, i^k\equiv 1 \mod p$, not $i$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433678/sums-of-powers-below-a-prime

Comment: I'm really sorry for the mistake...

Comment: Consider what happens when $p$ is odd $k = p^{n} -1$ for some positive integer $n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the well-known divisibility result

\begin{align}
 S_k \equiv
 \begin{cases}
  \, -1 \pmod{p} \, \textit{ if }\, (p-1) \mid k, \\
  \, \hspace{0.58em} 0 \pmod{p} \, \textit{ if } \, (p-1) \nmid k.
 \end{cases}
\end{align}

This is Theorem 119 in Hardy and Wright’s *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*. In [*Proofs of Power Sum and Binomial Coefficient
Congruences Via Pascal’s Identity*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0076.pdf), my co-author Jonathan Sondow and I give a very simple and elementary proof.