# Prove that, for prime $p$, the sum of products of numbers taken $r<p-1$ at a time from the set $\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ is always divisible by $p$.

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof

> Prove that, for prime $p$, the sum of products of numbers taken $r<p-1$ at a time from the set $\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ is always divisible by $p$.

One way too prove is considering coefficients of polynomial:
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)...(x-p+1)-x^{p-1}+1.$$
Any other proof will be appreciated.
The above proof of this on Introduction to Analytic Number Theory
 by Tom M. Apostol (Theorem 5.23).

Comment: taken 2 at a time ..1.2+1.3+2.3...... is divisble by p

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what "sum of product of numbers taken $r<p$ at a time from the set $(1,2,\dots,p-1)$" means. Can you give us an example, with $p = 5$, for instance?

Comment: I think an example with $p=5$ and $r=2$ is that $1 \times 2 +1 \times 3 +1 \times 4 +2 \times 3 +2\times 4 +3 \times 4 =35 $ is divisible by $5$.  Similarly $1 \times 2 \times 3+1 \times 2 \times 4 +1 \times 3 \times 4 +2 \times 3 \times 4 = 50$  and $1+2+3+4=10$ are divisible by $5$

Comment: 1.2+1.3+1.4+2.3+2.4+3.4 is divible by 5

Comment: It is not true for $r=p-1$: for example $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 =24$ is not divisible by $5$

Comment: r<p-1 ;sorry edited

Comment: For odd $r$, you can pair $a_1a_2\cdots a_r$ with $(p-a_1)(p-a_2)\cdots(p-a_r)$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Let $S_0=n$ and for $1\leq r\leq n$,
$$S_r=\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\dots <i_r\leq n} i_1i_2\cdots i_r$$
then (see [Newton's_identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials)),
$$S_r=\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=1}^r (-1)^{j-1}S_{r-j}\sum_{k=1}^n k^j.$$
Now take $n=p-1$ and note that $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^r$ is divisible by $p$ if $1\leq r<p-1$ (see for example [Divisibility of a power sum by a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111630/divisibility-of-a-power-sum-by-a-prime)).

Comment: @lhf See the link above.

Comment: thank you.... Is there more elementary proof avaialable?

Comment: @kuku I don't know... Now you have another proofs and several comments. Think about all this stuff!