# Sum of powers mod p

Tags: group-theory, primitive-roots

I've this problem that I did halve of the proof but I can't do the rest of it.

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. We define $S_n$ as $S_n =  1^n +2^n + ... +(p-1)^n$
>   Prove that
>   $S_n \equiv
> \begin{cases}
> 0  & \text{if $p-1 \nmid n $  } \\
> -1, & \text{if $p-1 \mid n$ }
> \end{cases}$

Partial proof:

If $p-1\mid n$, then $\varphi(n)=p-1=kn$ for some k. 
As $p$ is prime, then every number from 1 to $p-1$ is relatively prime to it. So, using the Fermat-Euler Theroem, $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1$ if $1 \leq a \leq p-1$. 
We see that every term in the sum becomes congruent to 1, and $\sum_1^{p-1} 1 = p-1 \equiv -1 \pmod p $.

I don't know what to do if $p-1 \nmid n $. I've tried taking a primitive root mod p, but I got stuck.Any help or tip would be much aprecciated.

Comment: As a useful first step note that for all  $g\not\equiv 0\pmod p$ we must have $S_n\equiv (g\times 1)^n+\cdots + (g\times (p-1))^n\equiv g^{n}S_n \pmod p$.

Comment: I don't see were does that come from, can you expand a little further?

Comment: Where it comes from?  It's a standard sort of trick for showing that various sums vanish $\pmod p$.  The point is that multiplying by $g$ permutes the non-zero residues (as $g$ is invertible $\pmod p$).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433678/sums-of-powers-below-a-prime and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234745/is-my-shorter-expression-for-s-mn-1m2m3m-cdotsn-1m-pmod-n-true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

Suppose that $p-1\nmid n$.  Then let $g$ be a primitive root $\pmod p$.  It follows that $g^n\not \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  Also, $g$ is clearly invertible $\pmod p$.  That implies that the list $\{g\times 1, g\times 2, \cdots, g\times (p-1)\}$ is a full list of the non-zero residues $\pmod p$.

Thus $$S_n\equiv (g\times 1)^n+(g\times 2)^n+\cdots +(g\times (p-1))^n\equiv g^nS_n \pmod p$$

But then, as $g^n\not \equiv 1$ we see that $S_n\equiv 0\pmod p$ as desired.

Comment: Oh, now I see it. As I wasn't familiarized with the trick, in my mind  it wasn't as direct as you though it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
1^n +2^n + \cdots +(p-1)^n
&= (g^0)^n + (g^1)^n + \cdots + (g^{p-2})^n
\\&= (g^n)^0 + (g^n)^1 + \cdots + (g^n)^{p-2}
\\&= \frac{(g^n)^{p-1}-1}{g^n-1}
\\&= 0
\end{align}
$$
if $g^n\ne 1$, that is, if $p-1 \not \mid n$.

Comment: That's a cool trick to have up my sleeve! Thanks