# Quadratic Gauss sum and a polynomial $ \equiv -1 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to solve problem 6.22 in Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* (second edition). The exercise is about the sign of the Gauss sum $g = \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{j}{p}\right)\zeta^j$, where $p$ is a fixed prime and $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/p}$. In the chapter this problem is reduced to showing that $\varepsilon = 1$ makes the following polynomial equality hold and $\varepsilon = -1$ doesn't (those are the only values $\varepsilon$ can take and we know one of them works).
$$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)(1+t)^j-\varepsilon\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}((1+t)^{2k-1}-(1+t)^{p-(2k-1)})=((1+t)^p-1)h(t)$$
Here $h(t)\in\mathbb{Z}[t]$ is some polynomial we're not interested in.

Following the book's approach I looked at the coefficients of $t^{(p-1)/2}$ in both sides. On the left-hand side we have $$\sum_{j=(p-1)/2}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)\binom{j}{(p-1)/2}-\varepsilon\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(4k-p-2)$$ and on the right-hand side we have a multiple of p, so equating mod $p$ and multiplying by $((p-1)/2)!$ yields $$\sum_{j=(p-1)/2}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)j(j-1)...(j-(p-1)/2+1) \equiv \varepsilon((p-1)/2)!\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(4k-2) \equiv -\varepsilon \ (\textrm{mod}\ p).$$ The second congruence is not hard to justify. However, I have no idea how to show the first expression is -1. I've tried to interpret it as the polynomial $$f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)(x+j)(x+j-1)...(x+j-(p-1)/2+1)$$ evaluated at $x=0$. I've expanded it for small primes and got that $f(x)$ is identically congruent to -1, but I don't know how to prove that in general. Any help with the polynomial or any alternative approaches to the problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ireland and Rosen show this also in Proposition 6.4.4., namely by applying Wilson's theorem and reducing to $\epsilon(p-1)!\equiv -\epsilon \bmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it!
$$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)j(j-1)...(j-(p-1)/2+1)$$
The trick is to expand this expression to get terms of the form $a_k\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{j}{p}\right)j^k \equiv a_k\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}j^{(p-1)/2+k} \ (\textrm{mod} \ p)$, with $a_{(p-1)/2} = 1$. The result of these sums is well known to be -1 if $p-1$ divides the esponent of $j$ and 0 otherwise, which solves the problem. The same argument can be used to prove that the polynomial in my question is actually constant.
[Sum of powers mod p](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814684/sum-of-powers-mod-p)