# Show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p} i^{p}$ is divisible by $p$ for all primes $p > 2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

> Show that
>    $$
>  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p} i^{p}
>  $$
>    is divisible by $p$ for all primes $p > 2$.

I think this has something to do with Fermat's Theorem and I have tried using congruences modulus to do it.

Comment: elcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529790/1k-2k-cdots-p-1k-equiv-begincases-1-mod-p-text-if-p-1

Answer (score 5):

Guide:

Notice that $p$ is odd.

$$1^p + (p-1)^p \equiv 1^p+(-1)^p \equiv 1-1 \equiv0 \pmod{p}$$

$$2^p + (p-2)^p \equiv 2^p+(-2)^p \equiv 2^p-2^p \equiv0 \pmod{p}$$

Something to think about:

- How important do you think $p$ being prime is here, or is $p$ being odd positive number sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

And yes, it can be solved using [LFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) as well, since 
$$i^p\equiv i \pmod{p}$$
thus
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}i^p \equiv \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}i \pmod{p} \tag{1}$$
but
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}i = \frac{p(p+1)}{2}$$
and $\forall p>2$ primes are odd, thus $2 \mid p+1$
which means 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}i = \frac{p(p+1)}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
and from $(1)$
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p}i^p \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$