# Sum equals zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have the following question.
Let $p \geq 3$ be a prime, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to show, that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^n \equiv \begin{cases} -1 \mod p, & \text{if } n \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1} \\
0 \mod p, & \text{else.} 
\end{cases}$$
I figured out the first case using Fermat’s little theorem and the second case, but only for odd $n$ since then the first and last $(p-1)/2$ terms cancel out. Does anyone have a hint how to see the result in general.
Thank in advance.

Comment: I'm confused about the first case.  Since $p-1$ is even, $n \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1} \Rightarrow n$ is even.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was expressed in a bad way. I figured out the first case. And I figured out the second Case for odd $n$. So $n$ will be even in the first case, but it can also meet the second case being even, which is my problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226023/congruence-modulo-p/226044#226044

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234745/is-my-shorter-expression-for-s-mn-1m2m3m-cdotsn-1m-pmod-n-true